# How to force Ubuntu to always detect my touchpad as AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint?

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, 20.04

On Ubuntu 20.04, the touchpad on my Lenovo IdeaPad Z360 sometimes is detected as AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint, sometimes as PS/2 Generic Mouse, and sometimes it is not detected at all. When detected as AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint, it works acceptably. However, when detected as PS/2 Generic Mouse, it acts erratic; and when not detected, it does not respond.

Is it possible to force Ubuntu to always detect my touchpad as AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue with my Lenovo ideapad Y700; after trying several things and re-installing Ubuntu twice,I confirmed that my system  automatically changes my touchpad to a generic mouse.

I have logged a bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1882388

**UPDATE**

I have realised that if I turn off the mouse

`sudo modprobe -r psmouse`

and back on

`sudo modprobe psmouse`

twice (or more) in a row the touchpad is recognised as such and starts working for a period of time.

Then, it is recognised back as a generic mouse and stops working.

It is a temporary workaround that may help you...